# Check if a value in one column is in a list in another column using pd.isin()

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I have a DataFrame as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x' : range(0,5),
    'y' : [[0,2],[3,4],[2,3],[3,4],[7,9]]
})
```

I would like to test for each row of x, if the value is in the list specified by column y

```
df[df.x.isin(df.y)]
```

so I would end up with:

[image]

Not sure why isin() does not work in this case

Answer (score 6):

`df.x.isin(df.y)` checks for each element `x`, e.g. `0`, is equal to some of the values of `df.y`, e.g. is `0` equal to `[0,2]`, no, and so on.

With this, you can just do a for loop:

```
df[ [x in y for x,y in zip(df['x'], df['y'])] ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let us try `explode` with index `loc`

```
out = df.loc[df.explode('y').query('x==y').index.unique()]
Out[217]: 
   x       y
0  0  [0, 2]
2  2  [2, 3]
3  3  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an other solution:

```
result = (
    df
    .assign(origin_y = df.y)
    .explode('y')
    .query('x==y')
    .drop(columns=['y'])
    .rename({'origin_y': 'y'})
)

   x       y
0  0  [0, 2]
2  2  [2, 3]
3  3  [3, 4]
```